# How to move terminal to the forefront using shortcut

Tags: terminal, shortcut

On my personal computer, I use Ubuntu + Guake and I got really used to pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> to evoke terminal (guake). But now I sometimes have to work on school computers where I am not allowed to install anything and unfortunately guake is not installed by default.

I was thinking about doing something similar with pure Ubuntu terminal - I want terminal to pop out when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key.

So my question is: can this be somehow done on Ubuntu without root password? So far I have tried normal key-binding strategy which worked for Sublime (now I just press <kbd>F2</kbd> and and Sublime just pop out) but it seems that there is a problem with multiple terminals run at the same time and I can not really figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To start new instance of native terminal you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

[Follow this link for more info.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal)